# Is this how you turned out?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the dialog from the Godfather movie:

> Johnny Fontane: Oh, Godfather, I don't know what to do. I don't know
> what to do.
>
> Don Corleone:You can act like a man! What's the matter
> with you? **Is this how you turned out**? A Hollywood finocchio that cries
> like a woman.

What did he ment by the phrase **Is this how you turned out**?

Comment: The phrasal verb in the sentence has been used as a copula (linking verb),  meaning to prove to be or to be found to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Turn out' means the end result or something that happens to be that way (often the unexpected one)

So, Don certainly expected the listener to be a man, not a crying woman.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/turn-out) defines 'turn out' phrase:

> turn out: *to happen in a particular way or to have a particular result, especially an unexpected one*

Comment: Short and cool explanation, now that's clear. Thank you.